# Creating Slider in wordpress theme with custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, pages

Im trying to integrate an html template.It has a slider.Each of the slide contains 6 images.clicking on the image opens a modal,which contain details about the image.Currently im implementing this with a single page of custom post containing 6 metaboxes for image upload.When it comes to modal Im stuck.
Is there a better approach for this

```
 <section id="products" >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-title">
        <div class="sticker">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
          </div>
          <h1>products</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eleifend odio nunc, ac commodo augue sollicitudin vitae. Donec quam risus, fermentum in luctus at, sodales eget mauris.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="products-grid" class="row">
      <div class="container products-holder">
        <div class="row products-holder-item">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row products-holder-item">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row products-holder-item">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-item">
            <a  href="#myModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" >
              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/news-img.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <div class="product-title">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>

              </div> 
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: In what way are you stuck? What is it you are trying to achieve exactly? Are you sure the modal script is loaded?

Comment: Actually  what i m asking is is there any better way to load the sliders.

Comment: Depends on your goal. You could asynchronously load each slide. What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps in your post loop you would need to add a condition that checks for post type, using the get_post_type() function.

So something like this:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
           <?php if(get_post_type(get_the_ID()) === 'your custom post type') : ?>

                    //Your slider code with current post data


           <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

you could obviously add extra conditions for if the post type isnt found or i have_posts doesnt return anything.